# Android how to show an image for a specific time in a layout and then show the content of layout

Tags: android, android-intent, timer, loading, postdelayed

I want to know how to show an image which is in my case a gif loading screen to show when opening the layout of web view to give it time to give time to load contents in web view.
Either i should use a timer for the image to load or anything else.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(net_fragment_1.this,loadinganimate.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    },1000);
```

I have tried this code but it is crashing.
Note- i am keeping loadinganimate class in the same package.

But whenver i am keeeping in different package and calling it by full path like com.xyz.xyz.loadinganimate.class
it is just showing this class and not resuming to the original windows after a period of time...

Answer (score 0):

remove handler and add these lines in to your code

```
if (webView.isShown()){
            loadinganimate.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```